# How do you share encrypted data between two different .NET Core Apps?

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core app and a .NET Core command line app that need to share the same database entries.  I would like to encrypt one of the columns but still be able to have the two apps read the entries.  I have been looking into the DataProtection apis for encryption but can figure out how to decrypt between the two app.  Any suggestions?

In both apps I have tried configuring the DataProtector with the same purpose:

```
_protector = provider.CreateProtector("TestEncryption");
```

However, when I attempt to decrypt I wind up with the following exception:
CryptographicException: The payload was invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share data protection keys between applications. You can store it in local filesystem, in Azure Storage or Redis caches, or use another third-party distributed storage. For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Connect to Redis database.
    var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("<URI>");
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Documentation: [Key storage providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers).

Comment: so if the key is obvious, another application having access to the storage can potentially decrypt the data ?

Comment: @SylvainGantois what do you mean by "obvious"? If it is stolen - yes, the data can be decrypted.

Comment: I was just thinking, if I store an encrypted string in a file with a data protector called "LicenseKeys" for instance. Another program having access to this file and the keys file could potentially use brute force and try to decrypt the string by testing multiple data protector strings ?